# Handle errors when downloading data asynchronously under IOS5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, asynchronous, ios5

I am a rookie in iOS programming. In my test app I'd like to download some xml data from a server and make some annotations from it. It works great, and as a next step I changed it to be asynchronous by dispatching.

Everything works great, but I don't know how to handle exceptions in this scenario? Where/how to handle if the server is unavailable? Where/how to handle if there is no network connection? Where/how to handle connection time outs?

My test code looks like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("test data fetcher", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSString* fetchedXML = [Fetcher getTestData:@"http://127.0.0.1:11111"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSArray *annotations = [TestAnnotation getFromXML:fetchedXML];
        self.annotations = annotations;
    });
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

Te most relevant part of Fetcher's getTestData method

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are third-party HTTP client libraries that make all of this trivial. AFNetworking seems a popular choice (my former favorite, ASIHTTPRequest being recently deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an NSURLResponse and NSError by reference to the sendSynchronous selector of NSURLConnection. When this selector returns, those objects will be populated with the data you are after.

1) Instead of passing NSURLResponse, pass NSHTTPURLResponse, which is a subclass that will allow you to inspect the HTTP status code (response.statusCode) for non-200 codes.

2) Check to see if the return value from sendSynchronous is nil and inspect the NSError object for information about the error condition. This is where timeouts and other connectivity issues will appear.

Comment: No, as I state in my answer, you *don't* check whether NSError is non-nil.  *error is undefined in the case where no error condition exists.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while this isn't directly related to your question, you might consider using NSURLConnection's built-in asynchronous request facilities rather than rolling your own with dispatch_async(), using either +sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: or – initWithRequest:delegate:.

In your case, from the method documentation:

"Returns nil if a connection could not be created or if the download fails."

So, you would have an idiom such as:

```
if (responseData) {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
else {
    // Read error and handle appropriately.  To see the error on the console, for example:
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDesription]);
}
```

The main thing to remember about this (and all other cases where NSError ** is passed in) is that you *never* read the error value first to see whether a failure happened.  You only inspect it after being told (in this case, by having nil responseData) that an error condition has arisen.

P.S.- In Objective-C, "exception" specifically refers to programmer error, so the use of "exception" to describe a network failure is incorrect.  That would just be a run-time error expected to be handled in the ordinary course of business.